# PHP object returned to ajaxrequest has boolean == true instead of data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a dynamic view with laravel, php and jquery ajax.
When a navbar button is clicked, it will send an ajax request to the controller which will verify the id send, get the data and return this in html format.

Since there might be multiple values send back which need their own html div's. So I've tried this using an object.

buttonclicked => ajax request to controller => Get data => format data with html => put it in an object => return object to the ajax request succes: .

The problem I'm having now is that The object does return, but instead of the html formatted data, it has a boolean set to true as shown in firebug.

I'm fairly new to Ajax and Jquery, and I'm sorry if this question has been asked many times before.

Ajax:

```
function onclickNavbar(id) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url:'/controller/AjaxController',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            var token = $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');
            if (token) {
                return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
            }
        },
        data: {identifier: id},
        success: function(data){
            var $Htmlselector = $("#contenthtml");
            console.log('succes');
            jQuery.each(data.html, function(key, value){
                console.log(key + ' : ' + value);
                $($Htmlselector).html(value);
            });

        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log('Error something went wrong. See response output:');
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
public function processor(){
    if(isset($_POST['identifier'])){
        $id = $_POST['identifier'];
        $db = new DatabaseController();

        $diensten = $db->GetAllDiensten()->where('parentcategory_id', '=', $id);
        $htmlObject = array();
        $counter = 0;
        foreach($diensten as $dienst){
            $htmlObject[$counter++] = "
            <div class='col-xs-2half card-column'>
                <div class='article-list header-card'>
                    <a href='/dienst/" . $dienst->shortname . "'>
                        <img src=" . asset( 'assets/img' . $dienst->image ) . "/>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class=".'article-list'." class=".'body-card'.">
                    <hr class=".'hr-card'." >
                    @if(" . strlen($dienst->name) <= 20 . ")
                        <h3 class='name text-card'>" . $dienst->name . "</h3>
                    @else
                        <h3 class='name text-card'>" . $dienst->name . "</h3>
                    @endif
                    <hr>
                    <p class='description idtagA text-card'>" . $dienst->shortdesc . "</p> 
                </div>
                <div class='article-list footer-card'>
                    <a href='/dienst/". $dienst->shortname ."'>
                        <button class='btn btn-danger btn-card' type='button' style='padding-bottom:10px;'>
                            <span>". $dienst->shortname ."</span>
                        </button>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>";
        }
        $htmlObject = json_encode((object)$htmlObject);
        return response()->json(['html'=> $htmlObject]);
        //return json_encode($html, true);

    }else{
        return 'Value Identifier not set!';
    }
}
```

note: I am using Laravel 5.6.3, The @if @foreach etc is syntax for blade.

### UPDATE: ## Error according to the code of @SmitRaval

```
{"html":[true]}Array{
"message": "Array to string conversion",
"exception": "ErrorException",
"file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Development Entric\\Entric_website\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\AJAXController.php",
"line": 49,
"trace": [
    {
        "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Development Entric\\Entric_website\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\AJAXController.php",
        "line": 49,
        "function": "handleError",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "function": "processor",
        "class": "App\\Http\\Controllers\\AJAXController",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
     .... It goes on for a while...
```

### UPDATE 2:

The are more functions like this, they're there now, so when some queries are used more often with the ->where or ->find I can expand these functions with different parameters. 
Dienstencontroller:

```
use App\diensten; // This is the model.
class DatabaseController extends Controller
{

function GetAllDiensten(){
    return $diensten = diensten::all();
}
```

Comment: Just something to mention: You define a jquery element with var $Htmlselector = $("#contenthtml"); and then you do $($Htmlselector).html(value); where $Htmlselector is already a jquery element. So you just need to use $Htmlselector.html(value);

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks for the heads-up! Will use that from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been rebuilding the ajax request and controller function step by step and testing every bit of the code to check where it breaks. Everything works great, until the creation of the object where the data is set with the with the Html.

I used Blade syntax in the Html, thinking this would work. Well it sort of did, PHP Recognized the if statements, but ignoring the Html with the data in the string. So it would just check if the Blade `@if()`statement was true or false,and since this block of code is used in a foreach, it would check every `@if()` in the object parsed, and the booleans would be set in the object.

So by removing blade syntax:

```
                @if(" . strlen($dienst->name) <= 20 . ")
                    <h3 class='name text-card'>" . $dienst->name . "</h3>
                @else
                    <h3 class='name text-card'>" . $dienst->name . "</h3>
                @endif
```

and just writing:

```
               <h3 class='name text-card'>" . $dienst->name . "</h3>
```

The object will contain the html with the data from the database. 
Should've known the `@if()` would create problems, since it wouldn't be do-able with php if statements.

Answer (score 3):

Why you are encoding json twice?

```
$htmlObject = json_encode((object)$htmlObject);
return response()->json(['html'=> $htmlObject]);
```

You can directly use

```
return response()->json(['html'=> (object)$htmlObject]);
```

Please try this in your code.

### Edit

The ajax call reads the response from the server, and that response must be rendered as some type of readable data, such as `application/json` or `text/html`.

In order to write that data, you need to echo it from the server with PHP.

The return statement doesn't write data, it simply returns at the server level.

Try this

```
echo json_encode(['html'=> (object)$htmlObject]);
die;
```

### Update

```
foreach($diensten as $dienst){
            $htmlObject[] = "
            <div class='col-xs-2half card-column'>
                <div class='article-list header-card'>
                    <a href='/dienst/" . $dienst->shortname . "'>
                        <img src=" . asset( 'assets/img' . $dienst->image ) . "/>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class=".'article-list'." class=".'body-card'.">
                    <hr class=".'hr-card'." >
                    @if(" . strlen($dienst->name) <= 20 . ")
                        <h3 class='name text-card'>" . $dienst->name . "</h3>
                    @else
                        <h3 class='name text-card'>" . $dienst->name . "</h3>
                    @endif
                    <hr>
                    <p class='description idtagA text-card'>" . $dienst->shortdesc . "</p> 
                </div>
                <div class='article-list footer-card'>
                    <a href='/dienst/". $dienst->shortname ."'>
                        <button class='btn btn-danger btn-card' type='button' style='padding-bottom:10px;'>
                            <span>". $dienst->shortname ."</span>
                        </button>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>";
        }
```

No need to give key `$counter++` you can simply use `$htmlObject[]`

### Update 2

You are not really fetching data from db.

```
$diensten = $db->GetAllDiensten()->where('parentcategory_id', '=', $id)->get();
```

Use `get()` to fetch the rows and store in `$diensten`

### Update 3

```
 $diensten = diensten::where('parentcategory_id', '=', $id)->get();
```

Add App/diensten in your controller and use the model directly. It should give you the desired result.

Comment: Ah, I might've overlooked the double encoding, applied your code in mine, it now logs the key and value, but it only displays the boolean: 0 : true.

Comment: Can you please show your JSON response? @RickJellema

Comment: in Firebug, the response returns: {"html":{"0":true}} or would you like an image?

Comment: Please check edit in my post. Let me know if it works? @RickJellema

Comment: Tried the edit you posted, didn't work; Response: {''html'':{''0'':true}} and in Firebug at the json tab it shows:

html                Object { 0=true }


0                     true

Comment: can you try this? 'html'=> $htmlObject. remove (object) @RickJellema

Comment: Now it shows me an error in response I'll add it in an edit in my post @SmitRaval

Comment: have you used echo to print the value of $htmlObject ? Use print_r($htmlObject); and see what array are you getting?

Comment: I did use echo json_encode(['html'=> $htmlObject]);
            print($htmlObject);
            die;

Comment: use print_r or vardump. Not print @RickJellema

Comment: I now tried             print_r(json_encode(['html'=> $htmlObject]));
            print_r($htmlObject);
            die;

It both returned {"html":[true]}Array( [0] => 1 )

Comment: Check update in my answer. Try that and print the value of $htmlObject. Let me know what you are getting? @RickJellema

Comment: it prints this: 
`{"html":[true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true]}Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => 1 [6] => 1 [7] => 1 ) array(8) { [0]=> bool(true) [1]=> bool(true) [2]=> bool(true) [3]=> bool(true) [4]=> bool(true) [5]=> bool(true) [6]=> bool(true) [7]=> bool(true) }`

Comment: Check for update2 in my answer. Use get() in your query. @RickJellema

Comment: Too few arguments for ->get(); tried the $id or 'id' / 'name', but then it just shows an error with an empty array just as before.

Comment: can you show the code of DatabaseController() ? @RickJellema

Comment: It returns the same as before; 0 : true @SmitRaval

Comment: I've been doing some testing, and using the $db->GetAllDiensten()->where($key, $operator, $foreignkey); Definitely returns data, I can even return that to the Ajax request and console.log() the returned data. It just breaks when formatting the data with html and putting that in an array, converting that to an object and returning that object..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167788/discussion-between-smit-raval-and-rick-jellema).

Answer (score 1):

in you php controller change return by echo

change this

```
 return response()->json(['html'=> $htmlObject]);
```

by this

```
 echo response()->json(['html'=> $htmlObject]);
```